# Coredata fetch request result doubles up after every request

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, viewcontext

I'm using core data to store my master data and update it based on user interaction view `UI` related to same.

First, I'm fetching some data in `SignupStepperVC` using following method and pass it to `SignupGroupVC` which is embed in `UIContainerView` inside `SignupStepperVC`.

So my code in `SignupStepperVC` would be:

```
self.arrSubCategory = TblSubCategory.fetchSubCategories()
```

where `fetchSubCategories()` is class method of `TblSubCategory` which will fetch all `sub-categories` from entity and return to `VC` where call this.

```
@nonobjc public class func nsFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<TblSubCategory> {
    return NSFetchRequest<TblSubCategory>(entityName: "TblSubCategory")
}

class func fetchSubCategories() -> [TblSubCategory]? {

    let fetchRequest = TblSubCategory.nsFetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "sName", ascending: true)]

    do {
        let arrSubCategories = try AppDelegate.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return arrSubCategories

    } catch {
        Logger.error("TblSubCategory - \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

`TblSubCategory` has following properties:

```
@NSManaged public var bIsSelected           : Bool
@NSManaged public var nId                   : Int16
@NSManaged public var nMainCategoryId       : Int16
@NSManaged public var nIsActive             : Int16
@NSManaged public var nGroupId              : Int16
@NSManaged public var sName                 : String?
@NSManaged public var sImage                : String?
```

Now using the ref of 'SignupGroupVC' I'm passing array of sub-category to it.

```
self.refSignupGroupVC?.arrSubCategory = self.arrSubCategory
```

In `SignupGroupVC`, I'm have list of group, so when select any group, related to that group all category will display in `SignupFirstStepVC`.

```
self.signupFirstStepVC?.arrSubCategory = arrSubCategory?.compactMap { $0.copy() } as? [TblSubCategory]
```

In `SignupFirstStepVC`, I have list of all `TblSubCategory` which are display in collection view. So when select any item from it, it will be selected and `bIsSelected` is set to `true` and again selection will set it 'false'.

**Code in SignupFirstStepVC**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {        
    self.arrSubCategory![indexPath.item].bIsSelected = !self.arrSubCategory![indexPath.item].bIsSelected
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

The using delegate I will pass array of selected subcategory to the `SignupGroupVC`.

This is flow of code where I'm facing some issue.

So, when I go back to Home screen and again come to `SignupStepperVC`, there are again method call to fetch sub-category.

So, the issue is, in database there are only 20 record, but when I go second time in `SignupStepperVC` and fetch `sub-categories`. I'm getting 40 record. 
Again I'm follow above steps and go back home screen, come back to `SignupStepperVC` and fetch `sub-categories` from database getting 57 record. It's random.

So, this is continuously increasing number of record even in database only 20 record.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: what is nsFetchRequest()?

Comment: It's fetch request for `TblSubCategory`. I have update my question, please check it.

Comment: Could you explain this line **In SignupGroupVC, I'm have list of group, so when select any group, related to that group all category will display in SignupFirstStepVC.**

Comment: What is role and relationship of SignupFirstStepVC with Group and stepper vc

Comment: Again if `TblSubCategory` is class then you don't need to do that `self.signupFirstStepVC?.arrSubCategory = arrSubCategory?.compactMap { $0.copy() } as? [TblSubCategory]` just directly assign it. and after that You don't need delegate to received updated values (i.e when bIsSelected) ; it will be automatically updated  to your group vc as well as stepper vc.

Comment: for me problem seems to be in the group vc. which bridges your stepper and first step vc. **REMEMBER THAT CLASS ARE REFERENCE TYPE**